# How can I get an approximate quantile from rockdb at a cheap cost with currently available apis?

Tags: rocksdb

I have a rocksdb instance, I am sure no more writes are performed on it, and I am going to open it in read only mode.

Now I want to get a key of approximate x-quantile. For example, if I have keys from 0 to 100, and I want to get a 25%-quantile, then it is ok that I get 25, or 30, or 15. But if I get 30 for a 25%-quantile key, then I must not get 25 for a 30%-quantile key.

If I just scan the whole db/cf, I can surely get a accurate quantile, but with huge cost. However, I can't afford such cost, I wonder if there are some ways to get an approximate result.

I have come up with some idea, but I don't know how to carry on:

1. Maybe I can iterate over one file from L0(suppose L0 is tiered), or the entire L1 layer. Since the above layers are relatively small, the cost is limited. However, I found no apis to scan only a single layer or a single file.
2. Maybe I can walk over the rocksdb's storage folder, find sst files I am interested in, and use some sst reader to parse. However, is it too hacky? I mean these are all rocksdb's internal implementations. Although it is open-sourced, there is no guaruantee that I can do that.